# org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servle while launching app in cloudbees

Tags: tomcat, servlets, zk, cloudbees

I am experiencing a class cast exception from DHtmlLayoutServlet to Servlet while I am trying to run ZK application in tomcat server in cloudbees SDK.

This works fine when I launch my app in my local tomcat server.

Exception trace from cloubseed sdk...

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
>   Jan 15, 2013 8:13:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   INFO: Marking servlet zkLoader as unavailable
>   Jan 15, 2013 8:13:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
>   SEVERE: Servlet  threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1149)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
>           at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.startContainer(TomcatServerBase.java:120)
>           at com.staxnet.appserver.TomcatServerBase.start(TomcatServerBase.java:190)
>           at com.staxnet.appserver.StaxSdkAppServer.launchServer(StaxSdkAppServer.java:69)
>           at com.staxnet.mojo.tomcat.RunMojo.runWar(RunMojo.java:217)
>           at com.staxnet.mojo.tomcat.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:171)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

I googled for some time and ended up in this [link](http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/10188) But It don't help my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar exceptions around here, for example
[java.lang.ClassCastException when starting tomcat loading servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769429/java-lang-classcastexception-when-starting-tomcat-loading-servlets) or 
[ClassCastException in Annotated WebService in JBoss & Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116519/classcastexception-in-annotated-webservice-in-jboss-java-6)
and others. You can google for keywords `standardwrapper` `servlet` `ClassCastException`.
I'm not sure but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769910/546117) makes suggestion about multiple copies or versions of the same library in the class path. It may be `zk.jar` in your case. 
Comment on the link you have provided seems to state the same:

> I tried to integrate zk into another framwork and I got multiple servlet libraries loaded by diferent loaders, that has been the reason for the error.

So you can try to find and remove extra versions of `zk.jar` from the class path including your app lib folder or tomcat global lib folder.

Comment: Making the servlet jar provided in my pom.xml resolved the issue.